# Export Related SharePoint Lists

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have two related lists in SharePoint that I would like to export to Excel so that the information can be viewed in a nested scenario as it is a one to many situation where list 1 has client information and list 2 has all the purchases related to the client. These are already linked using the OOTB Related Lists functionality in SharePoint. Is this even possible? I have already been able to export each list independently, but was hoping for a scenario where users could go to one Excel sheet and see all the clients and then expand/collapse the purchases.

Thanks!

K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use excel to create two worksheets and link them to those lists.Then create a third worksheet to join the other two worksheet. You can find more info : https://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql.

If you want to go further, instead of lists, you can have the data on an sql server (external content types/lists and BCS), so the join could be done to server and the excel would get all the data. It depends on the amount of data.